# Print line at offset X in memory dump +/- 10 lines on each side

Tags: memory, dd, string

I have a huge memory image I'm investigating and digging through (64gb+). Too large to load into memory/vim. I ran strings on the memory file with the offsets included and saved it to a file so that I can search for the indicators I'm interested in. Example output:

```
332327467 Washington1 
332327514 Redmond1 
332327536 Microsoft Corporation1
```

How do I take one of those offsets and print out that specific area in memory? Ideally +/- 10 lines from it (if there are even lines in memory). I THINK I've seen dd or xxd do it but I'm not sure.

Edit: Ultimately my successful work flow turned into:

```
strings --radix=d mem.dump >> mem.asc
strings --radix=d -el mem.dump >> mem.uni
grep "blah" mem.asc *or* mem.uni
*grab offset from beginning of line*
dd if=mem.dump  bs=1 skip=*offset here* count=100 | xxd
```

Subtracting from the offset to go backwords slightly if needed, and changing count= to go forward if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `dd`, you can use `skip=`
`bs` is how much to read/write at a time, offset=`bs`*`skip`. Count is how many times to read/write.
Example:

```
$ dd if=input of=output bs=1 skip=332327467 count=128
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this stop after a certain amount of bytes? I think it's skipping to the right spot but it keeps going until the EOF.

Comment: I think count=X is my solution. Thank you again!